# How to connect to IBM host on demand mainframe terminal from excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, mainframe

I am trying to connect to open session of IBM Host on demand 3270 mainframe session.

I am trying to connect to the screen using VBA and send keystrokes and copy/paste from excel from the screen. I have the code below.

```
Public autECLSession As Object 
Public autECLPS As Object 
Public autECLOIA As Object 
Set autECLSession = CreateObject(""pcomm.auteclsession"") 
Set autECLPS = CreateObject(""Pcomm.auteclps"") 
Set autECLOIA = CreateObject(""Pcomm.autecloia"") 
autECLSession.SetConnectionByName (""A"") 
autECLSession.autECLPS.SetCursorPos lngRow, lngCol 
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""\[eraseeof\]"" 
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strData, lngRow, lngCol
```

It gives me object reference error. Please help to see if there is any problem with the code.

Comment: Try early binding (project -> add reference) instead of CreateObject so you get intellisense/auto-completion.  Perhaps `autECLSession.autECLPS.SetCursorPos` should be `autECLPS.SetCursorPos` as you create an independent object of that name.

Comment: I am not sure which reference to add. Can you please name the reference . I went through the IBM reference however I was not able to find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ECL API for Host On-Demand is only available via Java.  You can use the ECL API with Personal Communications.  Or you can use the PCS API or HLLAPI API with Host On-Demand if you implement the IBM EHLLAPI Library for Host On-Demand.

Comment: We used PCS API dll in windows to do it. Thanks a lot for your comments.